# Is there a way to make the OK button of Modal invisible?

Tags: antd

Is there a way to make the OK button of Modal invisible?

by using `okButtonProps` I mean, without the need to use `modal.info` or customizing a footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , you can do it from remove onOk pros like this .

```
 <Modal
          visible={visible}
          title="Title"
          //onOk={this.handleOk}
          //onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          footer={null}
        >
```

here is the codesandboxlink for the same .

**Link**

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-haibt-zl2ss?file=/index.js:760-927

hope this'll help you !!

Comment: Thanks, In my case I'm using the same Modal for several purposes and I have a logic in onOK . something like: onOk={this.action === "Add" ? ... if it's not possible via okButtonProps then I'll split Modals.

Comment: You have to split modals because if you define onOk than it'll always show button either condition is false or true.

Comment: Happy to have helped :) If this does ans to your que than please consider this ans as marked..